# Блокировка таблиц Mysql

Tags: php_pdo, mongodb, mysql

Привет.

Возникла следующая ситуация:

В игре для соц. сети есть бот, который появляется через определенное время и который является общим для всех пользователей. Логика такая, что при нападение на этого бота, проверяется в бою он или нет. Если в бою, то в таблицу `battles` делается INSERT, если же бот уже в бою, то делается UPDATE добавляющий пользователя к команде против бота. Т.к в соц. сетях огромное число пользователей, которые одновременно могут напасть на бота, что ведет к ошибке и поэтому есть необходимость в данном случае защититься от одновременного **INSERT** и **UPDATE**.

Я решил делать **LOCK** определенных таблиц на момент вхождения пользователя в бой, но интересно мнение более опытных разработчиков, насколько это правильно и есть ли более подходящий/правильный метод.

БД: **Mysql**
Engine: **InnoDB**

P.S Lock как-то не очень радует, производительность существенно снизилась. Может есть какой-то более быстрый механизм в NoSQL решениях?

Comment: Возможно, что я не правильно понял вашу задачу, но разве транзакции ([PDO::beginTransaction()](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.begintransaction.php))не решают проблему?

Comment: @Deonis Спасибо за комментарий, но не совсем понял, а как транзакции помогут в данном случае от 2 одновременных INSERT?

Comment: @Sever, ну, если учесть, что одиночные запросы выполняются в атомарном режиме, т.е. один запрос - одна транзакция, то возможно (*повторюсь, что я могу не учитывать какие-то особенности операций*), ваши два запроса, можно объединить в один, используя конструкцию **INSERT… ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**. На мой взгляд, это может решить проблему параллельных запросов. 

И я не против блокировок, просто знаю, что это может значительно снизить производительность. Если один поток залочил ресурс, то сотни других будут висеть и ждать своей очереди. Может я и ошибаюсь, но по возможности избегаю блоков.

Comment: @Deonis, Я блоки не люблю и я их вообще никогда не использовал и надеялся, что и в будующем не буду. Про INSERT… ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE совсем забыл, спасибо напомнили, потестирую.

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментария от [Deonis](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/4058/deonis)*

Если учесть, что одиночные запросы выполняются в атомарном режиме, т.е. один запрос - одна транзакция, то возможно (*повторюсь, что я могу не учитывать какие-то особенности операций*), ваши два запроса, можно объединить в один, используя конструкцию

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

На мой взгляд, это может решить проблему параллельных запросов. Блокировка может значительно снизить производительность, если один поток заблокировал ресурс, то сотни других будут висеть и ждать своей очереди.